# Does (9/2)! have a real answer or not?

Tags: factorial

The TI-84 says 52.342777 but other calculators says domain error.

Comment: I think technically it doesn't since factorial is defined for integers.  But we extend the definition to real numbers using the Gamma function.

Comment: It is quite common for calculators to use the gamma function to do approximations to factorials. It seems true in this case: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=gamma%289%2F2%2B1%29

Comment: For non negative real numbers the factorial is extended by the gamma function which makes (9/2)! well defined, https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function (it's also defined for non integer negative reals). Likely some calculators don't use gamma functions and so return errors. It's the same reason as a simple calculator might return an error for square rooting a negative number.

Answer (score 1):

factorial is defined only for positive integers. But it is generalized to real numbers using the gamma function. For each positive integer n, you have  $\Gamma(n+1)=n!$. You have that $\Gamma(5.5)=52.342777..$

Comment: Thank you for creating Akinator, I have played it a lot with friends and family.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Gamma function we have
$$(9/2)!=\Gamma(11/2)=\frac{945}{32}\sqrt{\pi}=52.3427777 $$

Comment: I'd say this is an abuse of notation. Gamma function and factorials are not identical things.

Comment: Yes, sure. But this is the way to interpret factorials of rational numbers. I do not see any abuse in it.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the answer for $\Gamma(11/2)$, where

$$\Gamma(n)=(n-1)!$$

The gamma function $\Gamma(x)$ is defined for all $x$ except $0, -1, -2, -3, ...$.  The factorial function, however, is defined only for positive integers.